# Jenkins: How to make certain log messages from a tool fail the build?

Tags: ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a tool in my build process that is very tolerant towards errors and warnings. It will often only log them to the console but not make the build fail. Currently, I am using that tool in the form of an Ant task, but that may change.

I would like the errors and warnings to make the build fail. Is there any way to do this? Can I maybe monitor the console output somehow and make the build fail, if appropriate?

(Just in case you are interested, the tool is Sonar.)

Comment: Do you want Ant to notice the errors and warnings? Or do you want only Jenkins to notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin [Post build task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) looks like a good solution for you.

You can configure it with a regex to check in the build logs and then launch a script that can result in a build failure (using the `"Escalate script execution status to job status"` property)

Comment: How could I make the script make the build "unstable" rather than "failure" ?